# MVVM Light IOC Container example

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

I'ave been studying this blog post from Lauren Bugnion on MVVM light IOC containers and I there is one thing that really confuses me.

Here's a link to the blog post
[MVVM light IOC containers blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/c73feaea-8526-4055-b6bc-c51d90a0b09a)

I dont wanna quote the entire thing so I'm only going to include the snippet that I have a hard time understanding.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
  static ViewModelLocator()
  {
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRssService, Design.DesignRssService>();
    }
    else
    {
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRssService, RssService>();
    }
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
  }
  public MainViewModel Main
  {
    get
    {
      return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
  }
}
```

Now I understand the static constructor and everything but I can't wrap my head around the

```
  public MainViewModel Main
  {
    get
    {
      return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
  }
```

Is this function even accessible? and how?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is accessible whenever you have an instance of ViewModelLocator. For example, you can instantiate an instance in App.xaml and it will be accessible via StaticResource.

Comment: Could you give an example? Because in my App.cs it doesnt allow me to write
`public static ViewModelLocator locator`

Comment: Wow im stupid, missing a public infront of the class made me super confused as to what was the actual problem. Thanks

Comment: You can add it to XAML by writing something like <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />